# Prestashop: iframe audio autostart block

Tags: html, audio, prestashop, embed, autoplay

I have this `iframe` and audio play auto.
How can `autoplay` stop?
Audio tag is not allowed in `prestashop` :(
And embed doesn't have audio control.

```
<iframe width="300" height="62" type="text/html" frameborder="0" src="http://nadabrahma-hangtalmasszazs.hu/mp3/sangha-klangschale-700g-harter-filzkloeppel.mp3"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even through this is kind of dirty solution it should work:

Make a new HTML file and call it audio.html or whatever you want and put inside following:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://nadabrahma-hangtalmasszazs.hu/mp3/sangha-klangschale-700g-harter-filzkloeppel.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"
</audio>
```

Now back to the iframe you make the iframe following:

```
<iframe width="300" height="62" type="text/html" frameborder="0" src="XXXXXXXXXX"></iframe>
```

Just make sure to replace the XXXXXX with your html file like audio.html in case it wont work add full path like http://yourwebsite.tld/audio.html

Please note: The mp3 file is served through HTTP if you are using SSL (https) you need to reupload the mp3 to some HTTPS server (your server will work too)

Tell me if this worked if not I am happy to help further more.